# Azure PHP SDK 401 unauthorised error

Tags: php, azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to get azure media services job details using Azure PHP SDK. I could able to do this previously. But now it shows some error below.

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException' with message 'Fail: Code: 401
>   Value: Unauthorized details (if any): .' in
>   D:\mystack\htdocs\at\sites\all\modules\custom\ams\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php:382
>   Stack trace: 0
>   D:\mystack\htdocs\at\sites\all\modules\custom\ams\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php(276):
>   WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient::throwIfError(401,
>   'Unauthorized', '', Array) 1
>   D:\mystack\htdocs\at\sites\all\modules\custom\ams\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\RestProxy.php(141):
>   WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient->send(Array,
>   Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\Url)) 2
>   D:\mystack\htdocs\at\sites\all\modules\custom\ams\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy.php(86):
>   WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\RestProxy->sendContext(Object(WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpCallContext))
>   3 D:\mystack\htdocs\at\sites\a in 
>   **D:\mystack\htdocs\at\sites\all\modules\custom\ams\vendor\microsoft\windowsazure\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php**
>   on line  **382**

Any problem with azure rest service?

Comment: It looks like it fails to authorize. do you give it correct credentials? Show us the code

Comment: Yes. I can able to access the login info via initMediaServicesProxy method. But i'm facing issues with retrieving the information using getJobByName method